# start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline: The start_url did respond, but not via a service worker. Lighthouse Audit problem

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

I am creating a PWA that works offline with a service worker.

Right now it works correctly, but there is a problem in Lighthouse Audit.

When I run Lighthouse, in the PWA section I get this problem:
start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline ***The start_url did respond, but not via a service worker.***

How do I pass that audit, even if there are other audits that say that I have successfully installed a service worker?

My website is here: https://nariohtools.com and the service worker is here: https://nariohtools.com/sw.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The related code is here:

```
caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
  return fetch(evt.request)
```

You are opening the cache but you're not using the cached response and the request is forwarded to the network:

Use something like this instead:

```
caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
  return cache.match(evt.request).then(cacheResponse => cacheResponse || fetch(evt.request).then(networkResponse => {
  cache.put(evt.request, networkResponse.clone());
  return networkResponse;
}));
```

Comment: OK now I have passed the Lighthouse Audit. Thanks.
However, when I get offline, it works fine, but if I refresh the page, it doesn't work. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: The audit passes and the website is installed in the cache.
I enter the website offline and it charges, but if I hit refresh Chrome isn't able to open the files.

Comment: You should keep the `cache.put` logic from your previous code

Comment: I'm trying to do it but it doesn't work correctly, I don't even know if I'm doing it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, don't forget to unregister the previous service worker when you're trying a new one

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you struggle with this, there is a bug in Lighthouse that has been fixed in Chrome version 89.
https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-pwa/issues/20#issuecomment-773019940

Comment: Thanks for the update! I will test it to see if it works now.